# Filtering the row values in the pivot table which are equal to 0

Tags: vba, excel

I am using the code to generate the pivot table in my sheet.

In the table, I have few row value that belong to "0" and would like to remove them from the table. I recorded the macro for that and tried the following 
below.

> .PivotFields("Location"). _
>       PivotFilters.Add2 Type:=xlValueDoesNotEqual, DataField:=ActiveSheet. _
>       pt4. PivotFields("Sum of O"), Value1:=0

I get an error

```
Object does not belong to this property or method.
```

Below is the code I use to generate the pivot table.

Any lead would be helpful

```
Sub AutoPivot4()
    Dim ws4 As Worksheet
    Dim pc4 As PivotCache
    Dim pt4 As PivotTable
    Dim ct4 As Integer

    Set ws4 = Sheets("PS")
    Set pc4 = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(xlDatabase, "'BWPSW'!R4C13:R1048576C20")
    Set pt4 = pc4.CreatePivotTable(ws4.Range("A3"))
    pt4.AddDataField pt4.PivotFields("O"), "Sum of OVERDUE", xlSum

    With pt4
        With .PivotFields("Location")
            .Orientation = xlRowField
            .Position = 1
            .AutoSort xlDescending, "Sum of O"
            pt4.TableRange2.Offset(0, 1).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
                PivotFilters.Add2 Type:=xlValueDoesNotEqual, DataField:=ActiveSheet. _
                pt4.PivotFields("Sum of O"), Value1:=0
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Try changing `PivotFilters.Add2` to `PivotFilters.Add`

Comment: @Zac I tried this way With .PivotFields("Sum of O")
.PivotFilters.Add Type:=xlValueDoesNotEqual, Value1:=0
End With  I am getting application defined error

Comment: Could anyone help me how I could do the filtering of row values in pivot table